# Remove .html at the end of URL whilst rerouteing to HTTPS

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web

I need to redirect my website from http to https in order to use the SSL certificate, but I also want to remove .html at the end of URL. I can't seem to get it to work.

This is my code:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Remove .html from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

The following code disables the SSL and doesn't reroute to HTTPS.

Comment: Aha, so I should just switch the order?

Comment: Order is also fine. Test in a new browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
 # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

 # Remove .html from URL
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html /$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Make sure the browser cache is cleared before each test.

The problem is with line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` because the file does exist and the rewrite rule is not processed. So I removed it (Commented) along with next line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` that should be left if there is no directory inside `(.*)` and your tests go right. I did not test it with that `RewriteCond`, though. But I did with this code and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
#remove html file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.html will become https://example.com/file
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```